# Java EE APIs in the Web Container

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am learning JAVA EE through oracle documentation(which i feels is great BTW), but i am not able to understand diagram on below link can someone throw some light on this?(what does it mean?)

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/img/jeett_dt_007.png

Comment: can you link to the original page you're referring?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview007.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just shows you the APIs available in the web container. So primary components that run in the web container are Servlets and JSF, however you may have also JAX-WS or JAX-RS services running there. These components may utilize various APIs, like for example JPA to access data layer, or EJB lite to use EJBs included in the application etc. And it all relies on Java SE, so you can use any class available there.

Comment: I was confused about the way its represented. however i get it now.